# APNS Change Notification Messages

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I can receive push notification by APNS. I want to change this notification messages according to devices. For example i send "Hello username" messages to 2 devices. The first devices username is "Jack" and other ones username is "Jon". I want to show notification "Hello Jack" in devices 1 and show "Hello Jon" in device 2. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make relation with userName and device token at server side. When user(iOS client) sends device token to register it you need to store device token with user name. When you are sending payload to apns from server make the changes basis on device user name.

Comment: Does it make sense to you ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure those messages on the server before they are sent to the respective devices.